# Confused with Domainkeys. Help?

Tags: dkim, domainkeys

I generated a domain key for my domain at http://www.socketlabs.com/services/dkwiz and got the following two things generated.

**Generator Key1:**

```
Setting up Hurricane Server
Edit the configuration for the account you wish to add DomainKeys/Dkim to, click on the DomainKeys tab, add a new record and set the following values:

Field   Value
Domain  softmail.me
Selector    key101
Private Key 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

---

**Generated key2:**

```
Setting up your DNS
You need to create two text records to your DNS server.
Name    Value
_domainkey.softmail.me  t=y;o=~;
key101._domainkey.softmail.me   k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCvAF7M
8g+zQRr7LBoL145loq7FFlWcIwwVFhkIpmmSDd3nPqRZpc0KE7asJUBFhdG6
wSzslL2RJofWeHmq1yvJuWmegXhyzDvyxKBw9Ap/yQArQEbQcyinXe3lIuBD4ounZzgckwxncUL7Cv+cLF7/o+myj09ZVQVVF5apfZ7NFwIDAQAB
```

---

Well, finally what I come to say is I know that the second key is to be added to the DNS records and what's the use of the first key? Of course even I added this to my DNS I am getting error that my Domainkeys are not verified. What should I do now? Firstly, what's the use of the first generated key? I think it has to be pasted somewhere else in the server. If so where? I am running windows 2003 server with plesk installed. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please find the detailed screenshot here http://i.stack.imgur.com/gKlMy.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in you other question! If you don't know about DKIM then learn about DKIM.

DKIM is a public-key signing procedure. You sign all your mail with the private key (key01) and then let others verify your signature with the public key published in DNS.

But you have to sign your mails. Otherwise there is no way to verify something!

**And please *DO NOT* use the published private key from now on! By publishing it you destroyed the security!**

Never ever use an online service to generate a public-key keypair. They are then aware of your private key which is the worst case you can ever think of. Nobody in the world should know about your private key. Only you. This is why it is called "private".

Comment: Well I will change my key

Comment: How can I sign all my emails with private key?

Comment: This is a good question! But I can not reply in a comment. And I will not. So create a new question. BUT WAIT: First google about that question and then you'll find a lot of information.

Comment: @mailq- I searched it for hours together but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I am sorry that my Serverfault account no more allowing me to ask questions. I posted the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308712/how-to-sign-outgoing-emails-with-dkim-private-key Please answer it at SO. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You will not get help there! This is off topic there.

Comment: @malq - But I don't have a way to post this question here. :-( What should I do now?

Comment: My account was been blocked to ask question here.